# Multiple imputation - complicated variable selection in linked datasets

Tags: multiple-regression, multiple-imputation, mice

I attended the course on multiple imputations, where it was stated (to my understanding) that when imputing the missing data on some predictors we should use all variables that will be fitted in the model (except outcome).

I am using the linked datasets in my model.

1. dataset 1 is the person level dataset of demographic characteristics (sex, age etc)
2. dataset two is area level dataset with different indicators A,B,C,D etc which are more or less correlated with each other. A is the number of food outlets per area, B is the number of gyms etc. I use B divided by population size in the area as one of the predictors in the model and B has missing values. A, C and D are not used in the model.

The predictors in the model are B/population size  + individual level predictors (sex, age ...)

I do not see how it would make sense to link datasets with missing B value and use sex and age of individuals to impute missing values on area level. Should  I first use A, C and D to impute B and then link complete datasets?

I also wondered, I would like to obtain the pooled estimates from the model, is there any problem that I would modify B (dividing by local population size)?

Will it even be possible to do the analysis with with() function and the use pool() if I first use only dataset 2 to impute B variable, then link the dataset 1 to n imputed datasets 2 and then develop the models on these sets?

Comment: I would first join the datasets and then use multiple imputation to fill B via A, C, D. This will simplify the pooling etc.

Comment: I started doing it and realised that as I am linking the same environmental values to all people living in specific areas. If I link before imputation, I impute the same rows multiple times. If the values B is missing for area X, I will impute B using the same area leve data from A,C,D for all people living in X. That toes not seem right.

Comment: But how can the number of gyms vary in a specific area? Isn't it a fixed value?